# How do I get a return from an API using the block_io library?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've made an API call before but used request and a URL. I'm trying to use the block_io library using their get_new_address method. This is how I'm making the call:

```
    block_io.get_new_address({'label': 'test'}, console.log();
```

This console.logs the return. I'm trying to get the data and save it to variables, etc. I guess this does everything in the background and it really confuses me.

Comment: provide a different callback than `console.log` that consumes the data

Comment: I tried .then() but it logged an error saying it wasn't a function.

Comment: Use a function instead of `console.log`